# Possible Bug in using ListView in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, visual-studio-2012

Not sure if this is a bug, but recently I have been using ListView in Visual Studio.

I add it into the `InitializeComponent()`, the following code:

```
this.lvBeamValue.Columns.Add("A");
this.lvBeamValue.Columns.Add("B");
this.lvBeamValue.Columns.Add("C");
this.myListView.View = System.Windows.Forms.View.Details;
```

After which when I try to add (say a Label) using the designer, these lines are automatically removed by the system. (It occurs when I use the designer for anything else, for example, adding in an event by double-clicking inside the designer).

Of course, this automatic-removal does not occur if I were to code (say the event handler) in by hand.

Just to check if this is a bug?

Comment: No its not a bug, you should steer clear from trying to modify the `InitializeComponent` yourself if you have anything you need to do in the designer view

Answer (score 0):

How can you possibly miss this:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
```